# selenium webdriver ijavascriptexecuter executescript argument types

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am looking at the selenium-webdriver API for .NET at http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html. For the arguments on IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript, it states that 'For a number, a Int64 is returned'. What do I need to do if I want to pass a decimal (in/out) with this method? The Java bindings, for example, currently support both decimal and non-decimal types.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Since I can't answer my own question, I am editing the question.
I ran the following code to do test the argument types that can be passed to the ExcecuteScript method.

```
try
{
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        string script = "return arguments[0];";
    double d = 15.009;
    float f = 13.2f;
    decimal dec = 0.2m;
    int i = 8;
    object value = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script, new object[] { dec });
    driver.Close();
    driver.Quit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
```

The above code throws an exception 'Argument is of an illegal type 0.2 Parameter name: arg'. But the other values (double/float/int) can be passed and the return value is same as passed. The double should serve my purpose for now. I was worried that the webdriver would convert my double into Int64 when passed through that method. I think the documentation needs to be revised.

Thanks, Vaibhav

Comment: Have you tried casting  `object` to `float` and then `float` to `object`?

Comment: @FrancisP, wouldn't such cast (object to int and then int to float) loose the value after decimal point?

Comment: You are 100% right, have you tried it with a direct cast?

Comment: hi @FrancisP, I update my question with the code I ran to check the types. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution would be to use `float` instead of `decimal`.

Then cast `float` parameters to `object` and cast returned `object` to `float`.

Comment: yes, that works. As I mentioned in my edited question, I was concerned about passing float/double/decimal to that method. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you should leave it as it was and accept the solution. In this way, it'll be more intuitive for users having the same issue you had.

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question at that point so I edited the question. I am accepting your answer. Could you please modify your answer saying float and double, both can be used instead of decimal. Thanks.